# Android emulator not visible in android studio->sdk tools

Tags: android, windows, sdk, android-emulator, android-sdk-tools

[Android emulator package not visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QU4PH.png)

[no emulator installed error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TgRb.png)

i have described the errors above in attached pictures.

i am trying to install android studio, but i am not able to create virtual device as it is showing "no emulator installed"

pls suggest what to do in this case

i tried to search the web for the solution and i tried to install previous version of android studio, but previous version was not able to start and i didn't found any solution on the web except one person asking for images of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Tools" -> "SDK-Manager" -> "SDK-Tools" and scroll down until you see "Android Emulator". Check if you have to update it or download it.

Comment: "android emulator" is not visible in sdk-tools, "android emulator hypervisor driver" is visible which is not being installed, what can be the problem?, screenshot of the same is attached in the question